# Reason for not getting answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have recently asked 3 questions without getting any answers and getting very low views, I want to know why so I can maybe change these questions? Are they unreadable or not clear? Because I'm not even getting any comment.

Here are the questions [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630262/about-the-proof-that-lebesgue-measure-is-a-premeasure) [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631897/relation-between-sets-on-a-semi-rings) and [III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634185/question-about-a-part-of-the-extension-theorem-proof)

I think I placed a lot of question in question I so I reduced them in II, but the same thing happens just like whats know happening to III they just become inactive and get no more views.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you gave links to those questions. But maybe that's the problem --- are you doing things to make it easy for people to answer your questions, or are you doing things to make it hard?

Comment: I didn't give links because well if I did this would seem like a promotion for my questions.

Comment: Suit yourself. But how do you expect anyone to answer *this* question?

Comment: I'll edit them in.

Comment: So one of these question was about **15 minutes** old when you asked this (meta-)question, right?..

Comment: @GrigoryM Yes because looking at the questions above it and under it on the main page it would get no interest while others already had answers. I just want to understand if I'm asking my questions inappropriately so that I change them.

Comment: I started reading your question II. I immediately ran into difficulties. Is the square cup -notation a different notation for the union of set or does it mean something else? What are the sets $I_j^1$, $I_j^n$? What does ${\cal I}^n$ stand for? What are the $\tilde I_k^j$:s? You seem to assume that the notation from your textbook are in universal use and immediately understandable by all. I hate to break you the news, but this is not the case. Also, a few days without an answer is not exceptional except for the elementary questions.

Answer (score 12):

Your subject area is more special than average, all questions are notation-heavy, the three questions are all very long, it is impossible to quickly scan for the actual question and the actual questions are interspersed questions of "Is this a typo?", "Is this letter different from the other one?" who are rather strange because you are the one who wrote this stuff.

You do not tell us where your formulae come from and it takes a serious time investment just to find out if your questions are reasonable. Try to ask a minimal question and tell us where it comes from. Why is there a second equality if the first equality is your actual question? Why are there several questions in a single question?

TL;DR: Your questions are still TL;DR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will work on the other questions to make them better. Do you think http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634185/question-about-a-part-of-the-extension-theorem-proof is also in a bad shape? Its only a few things which I didn't understand in a proof.

Comment: @user63697 Do not misunderstand me. I do not say that your questions are bad or that you do not deserve an answer or even that you will not eventually get an answer. I just told you my personal reaction why I decided to click on to another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, at least I'll know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

Does your problem come from a book? If so, which book and what page numbers? This information often helps me understand the background and motivation for posting the problem. It is especially useful when I happen to have a copy of the book. Alternatively, if the book is available online, for example as a preview at Google books, adding a link to that may help.

Comment: That's great advice I'll see of the pages are in google books, thanks Byron. How can I post a certain page number from google books.